# Using same algorithm for signing and encrypting a message

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature

If we use the same algorithm to encrypt and sign a message, what can happen if the message is intercepted and read by a third party?

Comment: It does not matter, as long as it is not a weak or obsolete algorithm being used.

Comment: There is no such same algorithm. Only RSA uses the same trapdoor function to implement encryption, decryption, signature, and sign. However, the padding schemes are completely different RSA-OAEP for encryption and RSA-PSS for signature.

Comment: It is okay to use RSA-based signatures and RSA-based encryption, but do not try to use the same key for both algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Although the names of the algorithms are the same, they are actually a little different when used for signing vs when used for encryption. The only thing similarity the two algorithms have is that they both use the same [trapdoor permutation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1448/54184), conveniently called RSA. The difference is both in where certain variables come from, and the use of [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Padding_schemes), which turns the insecure function into a cryptographically secure and useful algorithm. Encryption often uses RSA-OAEP, whereas signing uses RSA-PSS.

So even if you are using RSA/RSA for encryption and signing, an attacker who intercepts the message will be able to neither decrypt it nor forge valid ciphertext without first obtaining the relevant private key.